# Add Blur Effect to Image on MouseEnter; Remove on MouseLeave

Tags: wpf, image, xaml, blur, effect

all, I want an image to blur (using the Blur effect) when the mouse hovers over it, and return to normal when the mouse leaves.

I'm using WPF 4, XAML, and VB.NET 2010 in a Silverlight-based project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is to use the `VisualStateManager` and modify the `MouseOverState`

```
<VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStateGroup">
    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOverState">
        <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimation From="10" To="0" Duration="00:00:02" 
                             Storyboard.TargetName="blurEffect" 
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Radius">
            </DoubleAnimation>
        </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
    ...
</VisualStateGroup>
```

You can use the `Transition` to control the animation for the Normal -> MouseOver change and the MouseOver -> Normal change independently.

Then in the control that displays the image have the following `Effect`:

```
    <BlurEffect Radius="10" x:Name="blurEffect"/>
```

[Tutorial](http://windowsclient.net/wpf/wpf35/wpf-35sp1-toolkit-visual-state-manager-overview.aspx)
[More information](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/72976004-495e-46f9-aaa7-ba66d5fdae66)