# Drop Shadow Effect or blur effect only on Image on-hovering in WPF/XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml

I have an image with a shadow property defined as follows.

```
 <Border Background="Black" Margin="42,180,368,38">
   <Border.Effect>
     <DropShadowEffect Color="Aqua"  Opacity="0.5"/>
   </Border.Effect>

   <Image Height="92" Width="97" Source="/Images/image_search.png" />
 </Border>
```

This produces image with a border. OK. But, I need the border to be shown only on image-hovering? How do I do that ? Also, how to blur the image on-hovering upon it?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this with styles and triggers.

```
    <Border Margin="42,180,368,38"> 
        <Border.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Border">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                  <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Border.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>                            
                        <Setter Property="Effect">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DropShadowEffect Color="Aqua"  Opacity="0.5"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Border.Style>            
        <Image Height="92" Width="97" Source="/Images/image_search.png" />
    </Border>
```

The first Setter within the Style explicitly sets the background color to null and the border thickness to '0' to "hide" the border. The Trigger sets the borders background property when the IsMouseOver Property of the border control is set to true.

Comment: Thanks Batuu. That did help me. Any idea how to blur the image on mouseover (I am trying out something cool like in Windows 8 menu hovering?)

Comment: Use the search function, or just follow [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060197/add-blur-effect-to-image-on-mouseenter-remove-on-mouseleave). Good luck!

Comment: when I used the code above got stuck with a problem like "The property 'Style' is set more than once". Oops.Where Am I going wrong?

Comment: Only the code from the answer, or did you added something? Remove all except one of the property assignments. [Look here!](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546964(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: Nope. just the same code enclosed with in a grid. It says, "Error 1 The object 'Style' already has a child and cannot add 'Image'. 'Style' can accept only one child."

Comment: An another thing, If I place the line <Image ..> after </Border.Style> tag, the image too gets hidden and shown only upon mouse-hovering!

Comment: The <Image...> must be after </Border.Style> To avoid the Image gets hidden, the opacity was the wrong property. I edited the answer.