# Extracting property value of image object

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml

I have an image that I want to add a **dropshadow** effect dynamically when ever the mouse is over the image.

```
`<Image Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" Source="/Start;component/Images/100px-The_alliance_logo.jpg" MouseEnter="MouseOver" />`
```

I want to extract the value of Name whenever mouse is hovered over the image. I have coded the following in C#.

```
private void MouseOver(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
            object ObjectName = new object();
            ObjectName = Convert.ToString(sender.GetType().GetProperty("Name").GetValue(sender, null));
            String Obj = (String)ObjectName;
            Obj.Effect = shade(Obj);
    }
```

I am getting an error in `Obj.Effect = shade(Obj);`, that says : "**'string' does not contain a definition for 'Effect' and no extension method 'Effect' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**"

How can I solve it ?

Comment: your question was tagged by an editor as ASP.NET. I rolled that back. Although it was somewhat obvious, please be specific when you post a question, I added the WPF and XAML tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insist on doing code-behind, which is *not* how WPF is supposed to be programmed, then you will need to do this:

```
private void MouseOver(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var image = sender as Image;
    if(image != null)
    {  
        image.Effect = yourShadowEffect;
    }
}
```

However, there is a good example of how to do it the WPF way [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12021131/drop-shadow-effect-or-blur-effect-only-on-image-on-hovering-in-wpf-xaml), I strongly suggest you take a look, because the code behind approach will lead you nowhere.

Edit:

In this example, `yourShadowEffect` is supposed to be a variable of type `System.Windows.Media.Effects.Effect`, in your case a `DropShadowEffect`. You can create a new one by calling the constructor:

```
yourShadowEffect = new DropShadowEffect();
```

You should not do this in your MouseEventHandler, but rather have this as a class variable, to save resources and not create a new one every time the user hovers it's mouse over the image.

Comment: I am looking to make a dynamic dropshadow effect, and I have got 12 images, so I want to reduce the amount of code. I am getting the following error, **'System.Windows.Media.Effects.DropShadowEffect' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'**, in the **"image.Effect = yourShadowEffect;"** line. Could you please explain the code a little? Thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: You should really do this in XAML. If you would repeat XAML code, look into styles and control templates. I will expand my example a bit, but do yourself a favor and look into XAML as a way to do this. Don't use code behind.

Comment: Thank you again. I ended up coding all the dropshadoweffects in XAML as I kept getting StackOverFlow exceptions.